# why this two MPI Sends behave differently?

Tags: c, mpi

I have a pipeline like pattern communication between MPI processes. where processes Send message to each other as pipeline stages. 
The following example shows three processes communicating in such pattern.

```
    #include "mpi.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    //declare stage function
    void* testcall(void* d);

    int main(int args, char** argv){
        int rank, size;
        MPI_Status status;
        MPI_Init(&args,&argv);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

        if(rank==0){ 
            int k;  
            int x[3] = {10,11,12};
            void* data = malloc(sizeof(int));             
            for( k=0 ; k< 3;k++){           
                data = &x[k];           
                MPI_Send(data,4,MPI_BYTE,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);   
            }
        }

        if(rank==1){                                
            void* rcv = malloc(sizeof(int));
            void* snd = malloc(sizeof(int));
            int k;
            for( k=0 ; k< 3;k++){
                MPI_Recv(rcv,4,MPI_BYTE,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);              
                snd = testcall(rcv);                        
                int z = *(int *) snd;  
                printf("RCV 1: %d \n",z);
                MPI_Send(&snd,4,MPI_BYTE,2,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
        }

        if(rank==2){
            void* rcv2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
            void* snd2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
            int k;
            for( k=0 ; k< 3;k++){
                MPI_Recv(rcv2,4,MPI_BYTE,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                snd2 = testcall(rcv2);
                int z = *(int *) snd2;
                printf("RCV 2: %d \n",z);
            }
        }

        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }

    void* testcall(void* d){
        int z = *(int *) d;
        int k = z * 2;
        void* rslt = malloc(sizeof(int));
        rslt = &k;
        return rslt;
    }
```

output:

RCV1: 20

RCV1: 22

RCV1: 24

RCV: 2136566600

RCV: 2136566600

RCV: 2136566600

I have one problem with the code though. Send from process 0 to process 1 succeed and give me the correct when I print it.

while Send from process 1 to process 2 seems succeed, but when I try to print it is just an unexpected number (as shown in the output above).

I don't understand why this two sends behave differently. (both are sending a value pointed by a void pointer. why the second send is erroneous )??

help please.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using `void` pointers and `MPI_BYTE` instead of `int` and `MPI_INT`?

Comment: yes, I am trying to make the function that each stage call generic. Each function will accept void* argument and return void*
The assumption is that a user will define a function with this prototype and also specify size of input and output in byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void* testcall(void* d){
    int z = *(int *) d;
    int k = z * 2;
    void* rslt = malloc(sizeof(int));
    rslt = &k;
    return rslt;
}
```

This code doesn't do what you expect. The `rslt = &k;` line overwrites the value of the `rslt` pointer with the address of `k` (and you do this in several other statements). First, this leads to memory leaks, as the address of the memory region, allocated by `malloc`, is lost. Second, `k` is an automatic (stack) variable at its location would get used for other purposes once `testcall` returns. It only works in your case because no other function call is present between `testcall()` and `int z = *(int *) snd;`. The correct function should be:

```
void* testcall(void* d){
    int z = *(int *) d;
    int k = z * 2;
    int* rslt = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *rslt = k;
    return rslt;
}
```

Then this line from the rank 1 code:

```
MPI_Send(&snd,4,MPI_BYTE,2,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

`snd` is a pointer itself. You are sending the address of the pointer and that's why rank 2 prints strange values. The correct statement should read:

```
MPI_Send(snd,4,MPI_BYTE,2,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Output:

```
RCV 1: 20
RCV 1: 22
RCV 1: 24
RCV 2: 40
RCV 2: 44
RCV 2: 48
```